How to login to npm in bitbucket pipelines when you need to install a private repo?
I am trying to automatically build a react native expo project via a bitbucket pipeline but am running into an issue of using a private repo. Our project uses 2 private repos and when trying to npm ci the pipeline gets an error that the repos do not exist.
I am trying to set the pipeline to login to npm with the following yaml file:
image: node:alpine
definitions:
  caches:
    npm: ~/.npm
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Build app
          deployment: test
          caches:
            - npm
          script:
            - apk add --no-cache bash
            - npm login --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ --always-auth --//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN
            - npm ci
            - npx eas-cli build --platform all --non-interactive --no-wait

where the $NPM_TOKEN is a granular access token from npm.
However I still get a failed pipeline with this error:
+ npm login --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ --always-auth --//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN
Login at:
https://www.npmjs.com/login?next=/login/cli/f646d749-3b42-4d6e-93f0-77f3fb5d5d08
npm error Exit handler never called!
npm error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm error   <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues>
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-08-19T15_02_02_788Z-debug-0.log


Have you tested this exact path on your local machine?
